# Bigquery - finding when a sum was reached

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to find at what date total precipitation crossed 2 inches in the year 2012 and in the following stn and wban values 722616 and 03032 using the NOAA Global Surface Summary of the Day Weather Data on BigQuery.

This is the query that I built so far:

```
#standardSQL
select a.prcp, concat(year, mo, da) as date, a.stn, a.wban
from `bigquery-public-data.noaa_gsod.gsod*` a
where _TABLE_SUFFIX = '2012' and a.stn = '722616' and a.wban = '03032'
order by date;
```

However, I am unsure how to actual output the date value where the sum of prcp > 2.

Any help is appreciated

Thanks!

Comment: Is `a.prcp` the accumulated precipitation on the year, or just the precipitation of a specific row?

Comment: Its the precipitation for that specific row (day)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a cumulative sum:

```
select *
from (select prcp, concat(year, mo, da) as date, stn, wban,
             sum(prcp) over (partition by year order by mo, da) as running_prcp
      from `bigquery-public-data.noaa_gsod.gsod*` g
      where _TABLE_SUFFIX = '2012' and stn = '722616' and wban = '03032'
     ) x
where running_prcp >= 2.0 and running_prcp - prcp < 2.0
order by date;
```

Comment: Thank you! Any chance you could explain what is going on with the query? More specifically sum(prcp) over (partition by year order by mo, da) as running_prcp

Comment: FYI: **sum(prcp) over (partition by year order by mo, da)** is a standard "window function" that sums precipitation in an "accumulated way". Each row sum only the previous rows not the whole set. That way, you can find out when it's over 2.0

Answer (score 0):

This can be done when you filter `prcp >= 2`

```
#standardSQL
select Min(date),stn, wban, array_agg(prcp) from
(select a.prcp, concat(year, mo, da) as date, a.stn, a.wban
from `bigquery-public-data.noaa_gsod.gsod*` a
where _TABLE_SUFFIX = '2012' and a.stn = '722616' and a.wban = '03032'
order by date) f
where prcp >=
group by stn,wban
```

If you are interested in the date in which the cumulative sum crossed 2.0, then use the window function as mentioned by [Gordon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50977688/1265980)